# reset php counter does not work in chrome

Tags: php, counter, reset

I count hits on various pages of my website in the back office, which can be reset in IE, however the reset button does not respond in Chrome.

here the button code used:

```
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="reset counter" onclick="document.location.href('mailing_stats.php?req=reset_counter4&ev=<?=$getrecent?>&wv=<?=$getrecent2?>');" />
```

here the function:

```
     case "reset_counter4":
            $add_current = date('d-m-Y').": e-views: ".$_GET[ev]." - w-views: ".$_GET[wv];

            $handle2=fopen("count_history4.txt","a");
            //input new value
            fputs($handle2,$add_current . "\n\n");
            fclose($handle2);

            $handlee=fopen("../count_email4.txt","w");
            fputs($handlee,"0");
            fclose($handlee);

            $handlew=fopen("../count_web4.txt","w");
            fputs($handlew,"0");
            fclose($handlew);

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.location.reload('mailing_stats.php')
    </script>
```

Comment: check short hand is eneabled in php.ini or not also let us know which php version you are using??

Answer (score -1):

you have to start your php code with `<?php` instead of `<?`

and you must remove the stray `=` after the tags and you have to print your variables to the output using e.g echo

```
 mailing_stats.php?req=reset_counter4&ev=<?php echo $getrecent; ?>&wv=<?php echo $getrecent2; ?>');" />
```

Comment: The way he's using the short-hand way to echo out variables.

Comment: Unfurtunately the new code did not make a change, I use pHP 5.3.3